# Getting intermediate tensors for attention weight matrices in QnA mobilebert tf-js model without python/ajax

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, nlp-question-answering

I have been using [tfjs qna model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/qna), repo [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/qna) for doing some question answering tasks. I wanted to access the internal model states for this model, specifically attention matrices for the intermediate layers that I want to display.

My constraints are that I cannot use python or ajax, this needs to work in a browser environment (thus using something like [bertviz](https://github.com/jessevig/bertviz) is not possible).

I found the part that calls the tf model which is linked [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/04b1051c881e209cc8e1a5b0079b75e14ac048a1/qna/src/question_and_answer.ts#L233).

It does a `model.execute(...)` on the question, passage to get a series of start and end logits. The aforementioned model has an `executor` key that looks as follows:

[image: executor ss]

I see in this a `keepTensorForDebug` argument that I tried turning to `true`, but that seems to just retain the output logits related to the question-answering only, and not the intermediate attention tensors of the mobilebert model that it is using. What I essentially need access to is a way to stop the execute function from disposing the intermediate tensors, but I have not been able to find a way of doing this. I did find the [source code for the executor function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter/src/executor), but was unable to understand how to change it to retain the tensors that it is disposing.

Please let me know and I can provide any additional details. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.